# Django static files load locally but not on development server

Tags: python, css, django, django-staticfiles, static-files

I was able to get my static files (CSS) to load in my local development environment, however when I push the changes to my development server I am unable to load the CSS. My local environment is Mac OS 10.9.2 and my development server is running Ubuntu 12.04.4 x64.

settings.py

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'),
)

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '#7h&rny3^hz&q6w-8$6k&+msh554$pz*tx@$lj(+dgctvuj2j%'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (

    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',

)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (

    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'allauth.account.context_processors.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount',
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',

)

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'pcatapp',
    'south',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'tastypie',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    #'django.core.context_processors.csrf',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'pcat.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'pcat.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'db',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

SITE_ID = 1

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

An excerpt from the page source:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/myapp/style.css">
```

My static folder is located at `myapp/static/myapp/style.css`. All help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I just tried setting my `STATIC_ROOT = /static/` and running `python manage.py collectstatic` which did not seem to change anything.

Comment: Have you setup your server to serve the static files? also STATIC_ROOT should point to a full path, /static/ means you are serving from your root folder static.

Comment: You need to setup your server to serve the static files. It's not handled in production by Django. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#deployment

Comment: [Here](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/)'s an awesome tutorial that helped deploy projects. Also have a look at [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-deploy-a-local-django-app-to-a-vps) one.

Comment: I like this post about serving static: http://www.hasnath.net/blog/serving-static-files-css-js-images-in-django-the-best-way

Comment: I've followed both of those guides which just led to more issues, new question posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24131830/django-using-nginx-to-serve-static-content/24131959#24131959

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and `dj-static` provided a simple solution

```
$ pip install dj-static
```

In your wsgi.py file:

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from dj_static import Cling

application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

When using djangos development server, I have found that this problem, and its solution normally lies in the URLS file (when DEBUG=True), something like this will allow you to use django to serve your static files:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    ... url includes etc.
) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

This will mean that any urls serving from {{ STATIC_URL }} will be handled by django, here are the django docs on this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

EDIT (Added solution for running under a webserver not django development server):

If you are running your project behind a webserver, and not using djangos runserver, then its probably best you dont use djangos static file finder, and instead use its static file collector and the webserver to serve static files, to do this, try this in your settings.py:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

then run `./manage.py collectstatic` and ensure your webserver redirects requests from `/static/` to the full path of your static files directory, e.g in NGINX you might do..

```
location /static/ {
    alias   /var/www/myproject/static/;
}
```

And apache:

```
Alias /static/ /var/www/myproject/static/
```

Hope this helps...