# Django using Nginx to serve static content

Tags: python, django, deployment, nginx, web-deployment

I am trying to configure nginx to serve the static content for my django project on a remote VPS. I'm using the following configuration for my nginx instance:

```
server {
    server_name myVPSip;

    access_log off;

    location /static/ {
        alias /usr/local/pcat/static/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
    }
}
```

I created the config file in `../nginx/sites-available/`, linked it to `/sites-enabled/`, and restarted nginx however when I hit `myip:8001/static` I get a django 404.

Comment: Have you made sure the files under /usr/local/pcat/static have the correct permissions to be read by the user running nginx?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't access your website by `123.123.123.123:8001` because that's the port django is using. You are supposed to access `123.123.123.123` (that is port 80) where nginx is running.

Comment: That was how I was directed to do it in this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-local-django-app-to-a-vps I believe that is passing the request onto gunicorn to serve the django app.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but nothing changed. I am still receiving a 404 when I try to access the static content

Comment: @haye321 what about using `root` instead of `alias`?